# Examine memory address in 2 different format (decimal & hexadecimal) at the same time?

Tags: c, gdb

This is my C code

```
C:\Codes>gdb var -q
Reading symbols from C:\Codes\var.exe...done.
(gdb) list
1       #include<stdio.h>
2
3       int main()
4       {
5           int a = 9;
6           int b = 10;
7           int c = 11;
8           return 0;
9       }
(gdb)
```

Value of variables a,b & c

```
(gdb) info locals
a = 9
b = 10
c = 11
(gdb)
```

Memory address of variables a,b & c

```
(gdb) print &a
$1 = (int *) 0x22ff4c

(gdb) print &b
$2 = (int *) 0x22ff48

(gdb) print &c
$3 = (int *) 0x22ff44
(gdb)
```

Examine memory address value in Hex for variables a,b & c

```
(gdb) x 0x22ff4c
0x22ff4c:       0x09
(gdb)

(gdb) x 0x22ff48
0x22ff48:       0x0a
(gdb)

(gdb) x 0x22ff44
0x22ff44:       0x0b
(gdb)
```

Examine memory address value in Decimal for variables a,b & c

```
(gdb) x/d 0x22ff4c
0x22ff4c:       9

(gdb) x/d 0x22ff48
0x22ff48:       10

(gdb) x/d0x22ff44
0x22ff44:       11
(gdb)
```

The question is; is it possible to print memory address value in Hex & Decimal in single command?

It would be very helpful if I can produce the output like this.

```
Address   Variable  Dec Hex
0x22ff4c  a         9   0x09
0x22ff48  b         10  0x0a
0x22ff44  c         11  0x0b
```

Comment: [Dare to roll your own?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+write+gdb+extensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to ks1322's user-defined command, [gdb python API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html#Python-API)
this adds a GDB command to print out a table of the various formats
It should not be too hard to add multiple parameters for vars to print out the table you want.

```
class Foo (gdb.Command):
      """dereference and print in various formats"""

      def __init__ (self):
        super (Foo, self).__init__ ("foo", gdb.COMMAND_USER, gdb.COMPLETE_SYMBOL)

      def invoke (self, arg, from_tty):
        ptr = gdb.parse_and_eval("&" + str(arg));
        val = ptr.referenced_value();
        print('0x%x 0x%x %d' % (ptr, val, val));

Foo ()
```

And a short transcript

```
(gdb) source foo.py
(gdb) foo a
0x7fffffffdebc 0x9 9
(gdb) foo b
0x7fffffffdeb8 0xa 10
(gdb) foo c
0x7fffffffdeb4 0xb 11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [user-defined command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html#Define) for this, though you will not get the output, formatted in the way you want:

```
define my_x
  x $arg0
  x/d $arg0
end
```